# I can't connect to mobile brodband, but it is detecting

Tags: internet, mobile-broadband

When I connect my Nokia x2 with my Ubuntu 12.04, it detects the connection BSNL GPRS, But i can't connect to the internet. When ever i try to connect, modem get disconnectd..what should i do?

Comment: Change to Vodafone or Airtel. Call BSNl customer care and tell them to activate GPRS/3G what ever you using.

Answer (score 1):

Guess what, I'm writing this from Ubuntu 12.04, using internet via BlueTooth by a Nokia X2!

While setting up the new device:

1. check the box: ☑`Use your mobile phone as a network device`.
2. After pairing with mobile phone, make sure to activate `automatic connection`. 
   To do that, go to the BlueTooth menu on your phone → Paired device → Scroll to the Ubuntu device → Option → Select "Yes" for "Auto-connect".

After that, on Ubuntu:

1. click over the network icon on the taskbar
2. select "Nokia X2-00 Network".

Now it is connected. You are done. Open the browser and open any page!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Nokia x2, but the symptoms sound similar as with my N900, with which I can only connect to the mobile broadband if I reboot the phone while it is plugged in with the usb cord.

This way Ubuntu detects the phone somewhere around the sim initialization, and asks for the pin code, which it does not do if I plug the phone in when it is already on. After providing the pin code, the connection works like a charm.